# How can I uninstall a VS Code extension if I can't open a VS Code window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed glassit recently and my window wont pop up and I cannot see anything, so now I have to uninstall it via file explorer.

When I tried to look for the glassit extension nothing appeared! What's the file name of the glassit extension?[screenshot of extensions in the extensions folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpW7P.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Turns out I was looking in the wrong folder. You're supposed to go to /.vscode/extensions and then look for the extension that says "glassit" at the end

I recommend not installing this extension as it can be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall extensions via commandline: `code --uninstall-extension <ext-id>`. To get the ID of an extension, check its marketplace page. It'll be in the URL. For [Glassit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=s-nlf-fh.glassit), it's `s-nlf-fh.glassit`. Note that uninstalling an extension does not remove the extension's files from your machine. It just makes it so VS Code doesn't "recognize" it.

Extension files are stored in `.vscode/extensions/` in your user home directory under subdirectories named by their ID. You can remove the files by removing the corresponding directory.